# How to make a function with a context inside in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Im working with matplotlib and for a certain program I need to change the matplotlib parameters only in a context, not for all the document, so I neeed to use this context with lot of parameters,

```
with plt.rc_context(rc={'figure.figsize':(10,9),
                        'font.size':17,
                             ....
                        'xtick.top':True,
                        'ytick.right':True,
                        'xtick.minor.visible':True,
                        'ytick.minor.visible':True }):
```

As there are lot of parameters in order to clean the code I have the intention of put all this code on a separated archive and later import it as a function,

```
def context():
     with plt.rc_context( ... ):
```

But it cant be made in this way, gives an error because the function is not "closed", (*SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing*).

My question is if there is some way to pass this "context" inside a function.

Comment: You need to `yield` in the block and decorate `context` with [`@contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager)

Comment: To create context managers checkout: [3 Ways to create Context Managers in Python](https://medium.com/swlh/3-ways-to-create-context-managers-in-python-a88e3ba536f3)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might be asking is how to create your own context manager that you can use with `with` (this is what [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68816207/how-to-make-a-function-with-a-context-inside-in-python/68816267#comment121617994_68816207) was suggesting).  But actually there's an even simpler solution than that.

`rc_context` itself is already a context manager.  If you want to make your own "version" of it that bakes in a specific context, you can do that with partial application using `functools.partial`:

```py
from functools import partial

my_mpl_context = partial(plt.rc_context, rc={
    # fill in your mpl settings here
})
```

And then you can use it like:

```py
with my_mpl_context():
    # make plots, etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your code work you need to use `yield` in the `with` block. And to make `context` a context manager you can decorate it with [**`contextlib.contextmanager`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager):

```
from contextlib import contextmanger

@contextmanager
def context():
     with plt.rc_context( ... ):
         yield
```